# ecs-cli refers to old cluster after changing default profile; doesn't show EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I've been using AWS's ECS CLI to spin clusters of EC2 instances up and down for various tasks. The problem I'm running into is that it seems to be referring to old information that I don't know how to change.

e.g., I just created a cluster, `my-second-cluster` successfully, and can see it in the AWS console:

```
$ ecs-cli up --keypair "my-keypair" --capability-iam --size 4 --instance-type t2.micro --port 22 --cluster-config my-second-cluster --ecs-profile a-second-profile

INFO[0001] Using recommended Amazon Linux 2 AMI with ECS Agent 1.45.0 and Docker version 19.03.6-ce
INFO[0001] Created cluster                               cluster=my-second-cluster region=us-east-1
INFO[0002] Waiting for your cluster resources to be created...
INFO[0002] Cloudformation stack status                   stackStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
INFO[0063] Cloudformation stack status                   stackStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
INFO[0124] Cloudformation stack status                   stackStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
VPC created: vpc-123abc
Security Group created: sg-123abc
Subnet created: subnet-123abc
Subnet created: subnet-123def
Cluster creation succeeded.
```

...but `eci-cli ps` returns an error referring to an old cluster:

```
$ ecs-cli ps
FATA[0000] Error executing 'ps': Cluster 'my-first-cluster' is not active. Ensure that it exists
```

Specifying the cluster explicitly (`ecs-cli ps --cluster my-second-cluster --region us-east-1`) returns nothing, even though I see the 4 EC2 instances when I log into the AWS console.

### Supporting details:

Before creating this second cluster, I created a second profile and set it to the default. I also set the new cluster to be the default.

```
$ ecs-cli configure profile --access-key <MY_ACCESS_KEY> --secret-key <MY_SECRET_KEY> --profile-name a-second-profile
$ ecs-cli configure profile default --profile-name a-second-profile
$ ecs-cli configure --cluster my-second-cluster --region us-east-1
INFO[0000] Saved ECS CLI cluster configuration default.
```

It's unclear to me where these ECS profile and cluster configs are stored (I'd expect to see them as files in `~/.aws`, but no), or how to manipulate them beyond the cli commands that don't give great feedback. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ECS CLI stores it's credentials at `~/.ecs/credentials`.

When you create the initial profile it's name is `default` and is used by default.  When you set `a-second-profile` to default, it sets the metadata to use `a-second-profile` by default but you still have a profile named `default` that points to the original creds.

My guess is that to see the first cluster you need to now specify a profile name since you changed the default.  If you didn't give your initial profile a name then it will be `default`.

`ecs-cli ps --ecs-profile default`

If you deleted your cluster configuration you may need to add the cluster again and associate to the right profile:

```
ecs-cli configure --cluster cluster_name --default-launch-type launch_type --region region_name --config-name configuration_name
```

I hope that makes sense.   Hopefully looking at how your commands update `~/.ecs/credentials` be helpful.

Some resources:

- [ECS CLI Configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI_Configuration.html)

Comment: Very helpful as far as understanding where the ECS-related files are and how they function; thanks! However I've removed the errant profile and cluster references, but `ecs-cli ps` still shows me nothing despite instances being there. The access id and key look correct (i.e., they're the same I created the cluster with), so I'm not sure why.

Comment: I updated the answer with a little more info on how to add back your cluster if you deleted it from your configuration as well as some external resources.